# How to fill dropdownlist in syncfusion grid grouping control using asp.net with c#

Tags: c#-4.0, syncfusion

Can any one help me how to fill dropdownlist in grid grouping control.I am new to syncfusion controls.Any one help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the dropdownlist in Syncfusion GridGroupingControl by using Rowdatabound.

Add the dropdown in ASPX file:

**[ASPX]**

```
<Columns>
………
<syncfusion:GridColumnDescriptor MappingName="Country" HeaderText="Country">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server" Width="100px"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:GridColumnDescriptor>
………
</columns>
```

Using Rowdatabound

**[CS]**

```
protected void GridGroupingControl1_RowDataBound(object sender, Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.RowDataBoundEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Element.Kind == DisplayElementKind.Record && e.Element.Kind != DisplayElementKind.AddNewRecord)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (((Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.GridCell)(e.Row.Cells[i])).ColumnDescriptor.Name == "Country")
                    {
                        myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
                        myConnection.Open();
                        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[i].FindControl("ddlcountry");                        
                        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Distinct Country FROM Employees", myConnection);                        
                        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();                        
                        da.Fill(ds);                        
                        myConnection.Close();
                        ddl.DataSource = ds;
                        ddl.DataTextField = "Country";
                        ddl.DataValueField = "Country";
                        ddl.DataBind();
                        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please let us know if you need any other questions or concerns

Comment: Same code I am using but it is not entering into first if condition.I commented that if condition and tried again in next if condition it is showing object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

The first if condition is used to fill the dropdown list for the record rows only. This condition didn’t execute in the time of initial grouping, because all the records are collapsed state and caption row only displayed in the grid. And also if there is no record in the grid, it will not execute.

If we have removed the first if condition, the code will be executed for Column Header and the captions rows. Caption row didn’t have the ColumnDescriptor, so this is the cause of the issue “Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object”.